# Deploy Nodejs on Heroku fails serving static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express

Im trying to do two things that i read, but its not working. The statics files dont found.

This not working:

```
process.env.PWD = process.cwd()
app.set('views', path.join(process.env.PWD, 'public'));
```

And this not working:

`enter code here`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heroku for some reason doesnt work with __dirname, so try to this:

```
process.env.PWD = process.cwd();

app.set('views', path.join(process.env.PWD, 'public'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(process.env.PWD, 'public')));
```

This is what work for me when i have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is because, Views are express partials which should be inside "views" folder like this

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

For static files (HTML,CSS, JS) they should be inside the public folder, so to server files from public folder you need

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Thanks